# Showing a linear form is a basis of $(\mathbb{R}[x]_2)^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Showing a linear form is a basis of $(\mathbb{R}[x]_2)^*$

Show that the linear forms $\alpha_1(f) = f(-1), \alpha_2(f) = f(0), \alpha_3(f) = f(1)$ form a basis of $(\mathbb{R}[x]_2)^*$

[image]

I don't understand, he showed the matrix is invertible, why does that mean it forms a basis?

Answer (score 1):

If a matrix is invertible, its columns seen as vectors form an independent set. Since the matrix is $d\times d$, where $d$ is the dimension of the space, this means that the columns of your matrix span the space and are independent, hence a basis.

It is actually somewhat strange to say, "As $A$ is invertible", since the invertibility in itself is not relevant: it is the fact that the determinant is non-zero that leads to both the statements that $A$ is invertible and that is columns form a basis of your space.